# to calculate driving distance between two coordinates on earth in php

Tags: php, coordinates, distance, latitude-longitude

Well i am working in a location based app and i need to find driving distance between two location on earth at the server end. i am coding the web service in php.

Till now i am able to calculate the aerial distance using the Haversine formula, but now i want to calculate the driving distance.

There can be possible duplicates for this question, but i was not able to find any help to calculate the "Driving distance" between two "coordinates" ie latitude and longitude instead of addresses in PHP

Comment: Use the Google Maps API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you started...

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/nav?q=from:Buderim,Australia%20to:Brisbane,Australia');

$details = json_decode($json, TRUE);

var_dump($details['Directions']['Distance']['meters']);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i want it between two latitudes,longitudes

Comment: @Saphire Just place the latitude and longitude there instead.

Comment: @alex, is this public API? Or just something that's used by google? If it is not public API (i.e., something that google says that it is public), it might be illegal to use it.

Comment: @binaryLV I think it's undocumented.

Comment: http://briancray.com/2009/06/23/calculate-driving-distance-google-maps-api/           http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/distance-finder-google-maps-api/

Comment: @AR They both mention JavaScript solutions. The OP wants a PHP solution.

Comment: @Alex,, this is not working ..its showing just an integer value int(2918)

Comment: @SAPHIRE, what else did you want? Isn't "2918 meters" a distance you were looking for?

Comment: Warning: I just encountered a case where `json_decode()` cannot decode JSON returned by `http://maps.google.com/maps/nav`. `json_last_error()` returns `JSON_ERROR_UTF8`.

Comment: thnx..well used var_export() instead of var_dump() and its wrkn fine

Comment: I think this is outdated.

Answer (score 5):

Use [**Google Distance Matrix API**](https://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/distancematrix/) :-

> The Google Distance Matrix API is a
>   service that provides travel distance
>   and time for a matrix of origins and
>   destinations.

Here is the code:-

```
$q = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco&mode=driving&sensor=false";

$json = file_get_contents($q);

$details = json_decode($json, TRUE);

echo "<pre>"; print_r($details); echo "</pre>";
```

Find out more at [Google Distance Matrix API](https://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/distancematrix/)