# Issue with code to find driving distance between two places with Google Distance Matrix

Tags: php, google-maps

This is my previous post on the same matter: [driving-distance-between-2-locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14590364/driving-distance-between-2-locations)

I needed to find the driving distance between two locations using Google Maps but rather than in JavaScript I needed it in PHP. The accepted answer on that page worked for me in what I was looking for. I needed this for my project and haven't tested my project in a week or so, and after doing so now the code no longer works. It took a long time to search and find answers just for the code to suddenly stop working.

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/nav?q=from:London%20to:Dover';
    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    $data = utf8_decode($data);
    $obj = json_decode($data);
    echo $obj->Directions->Distance->meters;
?>
```

That is the code, I've tried some var_dumps but I'm not really experienced enough to understand.

Var_dumps for each line:

string(56) "http://maps.google.com/maps/nav?q=from:London%20to:Dover"

string(76) "{"name":"from:London to:Dover","Status":{"code":610,"request":"directions"}}"

string(76) "{"name":"from:London to:Dover","Status":{"code":610,"request":"directions"}}"

object(stdClass)#1 (2) { ["name"]=> string(20) "from:London to:Dover" ["Status"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (2) { ["code"]=> int(610) ["request"]=> string(10) "directions" } }

NULL

I've no idea how else to de-bug etc. If anyone could help I'd be so grateful as I'm so disappointed it's just stopped working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Able to see a variable in print\_r()'s output, but not sure how to access it in code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322084/able-to-see-a-variable-in-print-rs-output-but-not-sure-how-to-access-it-in-c)

Comment: Just wondering if you added a comma and country after the place names might help

Comment: shouldn't this be your URL? `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=London&destinations=Dover&mode=bicycling&language=en-EN&sensor=false` https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/#JSON

Comment: maybe it should, changing it to that address i still get null though

Comment: And without the utf-8 decode? Also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211127/to-calculate-driving-distance-between-two-coordinates-on-earth-in-php

Comment: a blank screen without the utf-8 decode. looking at that post, the second answer given works, however ive no idea how to get the distance from it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

```
<?php
$url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=London&destinations=Dover&mode=driving&language=en&sensor=false';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$data = utf8_decode($data);
$obj = json_decode($data);

echo($obj->rows[0]->elements[0]->distance->text); //km
echo($obj->rows[0]->elements[0]->distance->value); // meters
```

Comment: @Lubblobba anytime glad to help, i believe your original url was V2 of the api and thats why it was throwing a 600 error and you were getting nothing

Comment: ohh i thought there might have been an update or something. thanks again!